# Are vampires a type of ghost?

Tags: vampire, ghost

Me and my friends are having somewhat of a debate to find out if a vampire is a type of a ghost or not. I am convinced that vampires are a kind of ghost, yet they are not the exact same thing; as how a lion and tiger are still different, but from the family of cats. Is a vampire a type of ghost?

Comment: Vampires are corporeal. Ghosts aren't.

Comment: You could probably get a better answer [here](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: you mis-compared, vampires and ghosts are in the supernal family, similar to tigers and elephants being part of "mammals".

Comment: Um...  No.  No they are not.

Comment: You really need to quantify the fictional universe you are asking about; vampires are different depending on the writer.  In general, no.. But it's possible that they have been depicted that way before, or, more likely depicted in such a way that the same thing that causes ghosts causes vampires.  (The Warlock books by [Christopher Stasheff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Stasheff), for example, have both often as a product of Telepathy/projection, Witch Moss, or both.)

Comment: how are vampires and ghosts not on topic?

Comment: @phantom42 He isn't asking about vampires and ghosts in any fantasy work, he's asking about vampires and ghosts in the original myths and legends, which I believe makes it off-topic.

Comment: OP didn't specify, meaning it's too broad as written.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR:  No, vampires are not ghosts.

Because the question is so broad, it is very difficult to say anything more with any certainty.  Therefore, I am forced to rely, for the time being, on the broadest definitions of the vampire trope, from the [Southeastern European pre-18th century folklore from which the modern trope has primarily evolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_folklore_by_region).

> Key difference: Ghost and Vampire are both considered to be supernatural beings. The main difference between the two is that vampires are considered as mortals, who live up-to 1000 years, whereas ghosts are the soul and spirit of the deceased.
>   -  [Difference Between](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-ghost-and-vampire)

The claim that vampires live for up to a thousand years is apparently based on folklore rather than modern vampire fiction.  In most modern works of fiction, including, most importantly, Bram Stoker's *Dracula*, vampires are effectively immortal, and can only be killed through specific means (e.g., a stake through the heart, exposure to sunlight, or fire).

The site linked above features this chart showing the differences between the vampires and ghosts of folklore:

[image]
<sup>Image Courtesy: fanpop.com, boards.theforce.net</sup>

Comment: "considered as mortals, who live up-to 1000 years" according to what canon? Many, many fictional vampires are effectively immortal. (but no, they're not ghosts)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - according to folklore, which is the most relevant source for an answer, since the OP didn't specify a canon or franchise.

Comment: ok, then, which folklore? not all vampires can turn into bats, or live in coffins, or look bloated, etc... some vampires in folklore aren't even dead yet.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - I don't see any claims that mention vampires being dead in this answer, although that is a common trope.